# Insert Query doesnt work sometimes

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, sql-insert

The PHP code to insert into the DB. The code sometimes doesn't work. Most of the time it does work.

```
<?php
    include 'connection.php';
    if (isset($_POST['docsignup']))
     {

        // prepare and bind
        $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO doctor_details(firstname, lastname, license_num, zip_code, city, state, email, password, speciality) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssissssss", $docfname, $doclname, $docid, $doczipcode, $city, $state, $docemail, $hash, $speciality);

        // set parameters and execute
        $docfname = $_POST['docfname']; 
        $doclname = $_POST['doclname']; 
        $docemail = $_POST['docemail']; 
        $docloginpassword = $_POST['docloginpassword']; 
        $docid = $_POST['docId']; 
        $speciality = $_POST['speciality']; 
        $city = $_POST['city']; 
        $state = $_POST['state']; 
        $doczipcode = $_POST['doczipcode']; 

        // A higher "cost" is more secure but consumes more processing power
        $cost = 10;

        // Create a random salt
        $salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');

        // Prefix information about the hash so PHP knows how to verify it later.
        // "$2a$" Means we're using the Blowfish algorithm. The following two digits are the cost parameter.
        $salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;

        // Value:
        // $2a$10$eImiTXuWVxfM37uY4JANjQ==

        // Hash the password with the salt
        $hash = crypt($docloginpassword, $salt);    

        $stmt->execute();

        echo "New records created successfully";

        $stmt->close();
        $link->close();

     }
    ?>
```

connection.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cl10-doctor");
?>
```

I have noticed the code doesnt work when i use Upper case in password field.

Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: username and password are case sensitive.

Comment: @MarcoMura That comment doesn't help.. Why doesnt it insert into the DB when the password contains an uppercase letter.

Comment: store your password in lowercase or uppercase.

Comment: Can't we mix uppercase and lowercase?

Comment: dont make it case sensitive.Let the user type what ever he/she wants but at background you convert it in either uppercase or lowercase.

Comment: any help on how to achieve it.. Sorry i'm a beginner

Comment: the password is stored in database in unreadable format so it doesn't make any sens whether it is in uppercase or in lowercase

Comment: 1 step :- convert the password in lowercase using php strtolower() and stored it in your database.  2 step :- at the time of sign repeat step 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66315/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-user3765203).

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it case sensitive.Let the user type what ever he/she wants but at background you convert it in either uppercase or lowercase.

The password is stored in database in unreadable format so it doesn't make any sens whether it is in uppercase or in lowercase.

Convert the password in lowercase using php `strtolower()` and stored it in your database

at the time of sign in repeat do the same as above.